# How can I convert single array to nested array in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift

How can I convert this array

```
var data = ["a1", "a2", "a3", "a4", "a5", "a6", "a7", "a8", "a9", "a10"]
```

to this

```
var data = [["a1","a2"],["a3","a4"],["a5","a6"],["a7","a8"],["a9","a10"]]
```

Opposite is very easy, but I couldn't find solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this `Array` extension from [HackingWithSwift](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/language/how-to-split-an-array-into-chunks):

```
extension Array {
    func chunked(into size: Int) -> [[Element]] {
        return stride(from: 0, to: count, by: size).map {
            Array(self[$0 ..< Swift.min($0 + size, count)])
        }
    }
}
```

The usage would be like this:

```
let chunkedData = data.chunked(into: 2) // [["a1","a2"],["a3","a4"],["a5","a6"],["a7","a8"],["a9","a10"]]
```

Comment: Thank you, I searched like topic title, and I couldn't find solution. This solution is great.

Comment: Great! You're welcome!